# Find all labels and literals without meta:resourcekey tag in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

I'm planning to write a console application for finding all aspx pages in a given main directory. After that it will open it with filestream and read it. If it finds any Label or literals without meta:resourcekey tag in a page, it will add it's Label ID to an excel file.

First of all, is there any open source tool doing something like this? Because I could not find it in google. I just need to get an advice for parsing aspx formats in a page. Can someone give an advice for this please? Or maybe some regular expressions can do this for me?

Comment: Do you have to read aspx page or do you have the option of viewing the compiled version, like you can access with browser?

Comment: I need to read all aspx pages under my main directory and find all Labels without meta:resourcekey tag

Comment: I tried HTMLAgilityPack but it only gets nodes of html not asp:label or asp:buttons.